# N by N matrix diagonal difference

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Hi I have this following code snippet for getting the difference in an N by N array but it does not seem to be giving me the correct answers I got the algorithm by drawing the N by N matrix on paper and working it out, It does not give me any bugs but does not give me the answer I expect to receive, what am I missing out on

```
   //includes here
int main(){
    int n;
    int diagOne{0};
    int diagTwo{0};
    cin >> n;
    vector< vector<int> > a(n,vector<int>(n));
    for(int a_i = 0;a_i < n;a_i++){
       for(int a_j = 0;a_j < n;a_j++){
          cin >> a[a_i][a_j];
           if (a_i==a_i){
               diagOne+=a[a_i][a_j];

           }
           else if(a_i+a_j==n-1) {
               diagTwo+=a[a_i][a_j];
           }

       }
        int sum =abs(diagOne -diagTwo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the expected/actual answers? Also, your code has a bug if it doesn't give you the correct answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Turn on more compiler warnings, this is a simple typo the compiler can catch for you.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you're after. Are you trying to calculate the difference between the [main diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) and the anti-diagonal?

Comment: Yes Im trying to calculate the difference between the main diagonal and antidiagonal, the first loop is supposed to be a_i==a_j

Comment: @BrianDlamini Thanks for clarifying that. I've updated my answer with a fixed (I hope) version of your code.

Comment: @Judge thanks it worked very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` in the second `for` is always true  `a_i==a_i`.

Comment: Thanks Ive updated the solution but it does not seem to give the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Milos Radosavljevic's answer, your `int sum =abs(diagOne -diagTwo);` is overwriting itself every outer loop. To fix this move it outside the outer loop. [Here is a live demo of the fixed version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a8ac981380a8156).

Note that this calculates the difference between the sum of the main diagonal and the anti diagonal (trace minus anti-trace). If however, you were after the element-wise difference total then you could [do this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af23e27c460a4f87).

Comment: This is dangerously close to comment territory.

Comment: @erip Yeah I agree, although I have added to it now, so that it both answers OPs question and makes my suggestion. Thanks for the feedback.